# Share lua data between blocks?

Tags: nginx, lua, symfony

I'm trying to use lua to serve 301 redirects directly from nginx instead of having to go through php or other stuffs.

I'm inspired by this article here:

http://www.agileweboperations.com/supporting-millions-of-pretty-url-rewrites-in-nginx-with-lua-and-redis

The idea is that I can save a list of redirects directly to redis, then match and serve them with lua directly within nginx to increase performance.

Since the backend project is Symfony, I have to find a way to tweak the code a bit to suit my need, below is what I have:

Here I try to match the usual mysite.com/this/that requests. I include the lua script to handle the redirection first, if nothing match I let nginx try_files

```
location / {
    include /etc/nginx/include.d/lua_st_redis_rewrites.lua;
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}
location @rewriteapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
}
```

Since I want to support the dev environment, I have to handle url like this as well: mysite.com/app_dev.php/this/that

These urls will not match the location / block so I have to call include lua here again. The problem is that now the links mysite.com/this/that will actually call the lua script twice.

My idea is that I can init a true/false flag in the first call and then use it in the second call to check if the script is already included? At this stage I'm quite confused with the scope of variable however:

```
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server from upstream phpfcgi
location ~ ^/(app|app_dev)\.php(/|$) {
    # # Setup var defaults
    # set $no_cache "";

    include /etc/nginx/include.d/lua_st_redis_rewrites.lua;

    # some more usual code for symfony here
}
```

1. Should I use global variables in this case to share data among 2 blocks of lua code? I see the use of global variables is strongly discouraged?
2. If I include the lua script twice, can I safely assume that variables declared in the script will always be re-declared every time it is called?

Thank you, I'm completely new to this so please forgive my obvious question.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can't include Lua files directly like that. Assuming you are using Openresty you need to use the relevant *_by_lua phase to process the request, in this case [rewrite_by_lua](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#rewrite_by_lua_block).

Different blocks can't access each others globals but you can use the [ngx.ctx](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxctx) table which sticks around for the duration of the request.

There's a handy diagram of the openresty phases [here](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2137369/15272097/77d1c09e-1a37-11e6-97ef-d9767035fc3e.png).

Comment: Thank you I will look into ngx.ctx, seems like what I need. Oddly enough the include does work as shown on the script, though I suspect your suggested way may be a better way to do it

Comment: Just an update: ngx.ctx only holds value within that specific request/sub request so it doesn't work for me because it means data is not share in those 2 location blocks above in my example. So now I'm looking into using module local foo = require "foo" but the issue is that module keeps the data shared in all requests as long as the nginx worker is still alive.